# Distribute prizes for a tournament system

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I'm looking for a way to distribute a number across x units. I don't even know how to put this words so I'll give an example:

There's a tournament in which the total prize is $1000. I want that the top 20 winners/entrants will win something out of it.
I need a mathematical algorithm/formula which will distibute it across those players, and which gives me the power to control certain other factors of the distribution.

A factor for example is that I want the top #1 winner will get $300. The top #2 winner will get smaller percentage of it. The total distribution must give everyone something, until the top #20 winner (the last one) which will get at least X$.
X$ is another factor I want to control.

Any idea? Does this problem has a name (and what's that name is)? Any code example?

**Edit #1 - my first proposal**:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>

#define TOTAL                       100
#define WINNERS                     15
#define FIRST_WINNER_PERCENTAGE     0.30

void distribute_1(::std::vector<double> * const prizes)
{
    prizes->clear();

    double total = TOTAL;
    double winning_percentage = FIRST_WINNER_PERCENTAGE;
    double slope = 0.5;
    int winners = WINNERS;

    double winning = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < winners; i++, total -= winning, winning_percentage /= 2)
    {
        winning = total * winning_percentage;
        prizes->push_back(winning);
    }
}
void distribute_2(::std::vector<double> * const prizes)
{
    prizes->clear();

    double total = TOTAL;
    double winning_percentage = FIRST_WINNER_PERCENTAGE;
    double slope = 0.5;
    int winners = WINNERS;

    double winning = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < winners; i++, total -= winning/*, winning_percentage /= 2*/)
    {
        winning = total * winning_percentage;
        prizes->push_back(winning);
    }
}
void distribute_3(::std::vector<double> * const prizes)
{
    prizes->clear();

    double total = TOTAL;
    double winning_percentage = FIRST_WINNER_PERCENTAGE;
    double slope = 0.0005;
    int winners = WINNERS;

    double winning = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < winners; i++, total -= winning, winning_percentage -= slope)
    {
        winning = total * winning_percentage;
        prizes->push_back(winning);
    }
}
void distribute_4(::std::vector<double> * const prizes)
{
    prizes->clear();

    double total = TOTAL;
    double winning_percentage = FIRST_WINNER_PERCENTAGE;
    double slope = 1 / WINNERS;
    int winners = WINNERS;

    double winning = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < winners; i++, total -= winning, winning_percentage -= slope)
    {
        winning = total * winning_percentage;
        prizes->push_back(winning);
    }
}

void main()
{
    ::std::vector<double> prizes;

    distribute_1(&prizes);
    distribute_2(&prizes);
    distribute_3(&prizes);
    distribute_4(&prizes);

    double total_granted = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < WINNERS; i++)
    {
        total_granted += prizes[i];
        printf("%lf\n", prizes[i]);
    }
    printf("-\n%lf\n", total_granted);

    _getch();
}
```

This is as far as I could reach. The issue with this one is for example, if that if you set 'WINNERS' to 5 for example, the algorithm doesn't reach the 'TOTAL' amount (100 in this example) or even closer (I get a total of 83).

**Cristy's solution**:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include<iostream>
//using arithmetic progression
using namespace std;
int i;
float ratio;
float first_prize;
float s;
int main()
{
    float money=1000;
    const int total_prizes =        10;
    float last_prize =              99;
    float prizes[total_prizes+1];

    /**/first_prize=2*money/total_prizes-last_prize; //last member of the progresion
    ratio=(first_prize-last_prize)/(total_prizes-1);
    prizes[total_prizes]=last_prize;
    for(i=total_prizes-1;i>=1;i--){
       prizes[i]=prizes[i+1]+ratio;
       money-=prizes[i];
    }
    for(i=1;i<=total_prizes;i++){
        printf("%d) %.2f\n",i,prizes[i]);
        s+=prizes[i];
    }
    printf("TOTAL SUM:%.2f\n",s);
    printf("Ratio: %.2f", ratio);
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Without more constraints, it's not possible to define an algorithm!  What sort of distribution do you want?  Linear?  Quadratic?  Something else?

Comment: There are literally countless ways that you could do this, and it isn't really a programming related question at this stage.

Comment: Also, besides the two factors mentioned above I'd like to control another factor which I define as a "momentum": The stepping in which the prizes will reduce, from the #1 winner to the #20 (last).

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Believe me I have no idea how to call it. I was hoping you could suggest (: @torak: I'm sure there are several ways to do it, and yes, I do consider this a programming related question, otherwise we wouldn't have the "math" tag as well.

Comment: @Poni: well you now have 4 constraints (total, max, min, and slope) which are likely to be incompatible.

Comment: @Poni: well, give us an example.  What would #2, #3 and #4 get?

Comment: Example distribution: 300, 200, 100, 70.... 1. Numbers may not be 1:1 with the example, that's my problem essentially.

Comment: What's the rule?  Without a definition of the relationship between position and percentage, then it's impossible to write any code.

Comment: It's more of a math question my friend. See? There's no "rule" - I want it to be depend on several constraints, as you said, total, max, min, and slope. If it makes it easier on you, I'll be thankful for a formula in which you'll set the numbers, and I'll modify as I see fits.

Comment: That's my point!  There is no way to satisfy all those constraints simultaneously (unless you happen to pick them just so).  And in your example, there isn't a constant slope!

Comment: Be imaginative - determine a slope which you think might work this problem out.

Comment: Even if slope is taken out as a constraint, it's still not possible to satisfy the other three simultaneously.  Look, it really sounds as if you don't know what you want, in which case we won't be able to help you!

Comment: I'll tell you that straight: I don't do what is possible, so all bets are off, or in other words, right, I don't really know what I want, or how. Tell me, what if I'd tell you I want to distribute it in a linear fashion? Say, we take into consideration only the total amount (1000) and number of winners (20)? I'll let you decide of a (constant) slope. What then?

Comment: If you have {max,total,number}, then simple algebra will give you the rest, as you're after an arithmetic sequence (see http://en.wikipedia.org/en/Arithmetic_sequence).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_sequence

Comment: @Oli: Thanks a lot that's one. Second, I think that in the wiki article I'll need to use the "Product" clause. I'm having difficulties to translate it into code, can't understand all the terms they use in the math formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's 1:15 AM here and I'm solving maths :)).
Using arithmetic progression.
I made all using defines so you can easily change them.

```
#include<iostream>
//using arithmetic progression
using namespace std;
FILE *g=fopen("output.out","w");
#define last_prize 10
#define total_prizes 20
int i;
float prizes[total_prizes+1];
float money=1000;
float ratio;
float first_prize;
float s;
//a1=last_prize
//an=first_prize
int main(){
 first_prize=2*money/total_prizes+last_prize; //last member of the progresion
 ratio=(first_prize-last_prize)/(total_prizes-1);
 prizes[total_prizes]=last_prize;
    for(i=total_prizes-1;i>=1;i--)
       prizes[i]=prizes[i+1]+ratio;
 for(i=1;i<=total_prizes;i++){
  fprintf(g,"%d) %.2f\n",i,prizes[i]);
  s+=prizes[i];
 }
 fprintf(g,"TOTAL SUM:%.2f",s);
return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1) 90.00
2) 85.79
3) 81.58
4) 77.37
5) 73.16
6) 68.95
7) 64.74
8) 60.53
9) 56.32
10) 52.11
11) 47.89
12) 43.68
13) 39.47
14) 35.26
15) 31.05
16) 26.84
17) 22.63
18) 18.42
19) 14.21
20) 10.00
TOTAL SUM:1000.00
```

As you can see they sum up to exactly 1000.00$ :D

Other results:
INPUT:

```
#define last_prize 30
#define total_prizes 5
```

OUTPUT:

```
1) 370.00
2) 285.00
3) 200.00
4) 115.00
5) 30.00
TOTAL SUM:1000.00
```

Comment: !!!!! @#$#@ !!!!!!!!! You've just put THISSSSS big smile on my face!!! It's 01:15 in here as well! Where do you live? Again, thank you so much, no words to express it! I'm going to play/learn your code through the rest of the night (: ! I understand you implemented the formula at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_sequence right?

Comment: Yes, 2 formula's from there. I live in Romania :) and I think I'll go to sleep. No problem mate for this code, I love to make algorithms :D.
If there's anyhing in the code you don't understand, just ask.
Good night!

Comment: Problem with the following constraints: money=1000. last_prize=100. total_prizes=20. The #1 winner gets zero. The #19 gets 94.74. The #20 gets 100. Any way to solve it? Maybe tomorrow? (: And have a wonderful night!

Comment: The code is not working because the last place can't be 100$. 100$ is the smallest prize so that a minimum of 20*100$=2.000$ should be paid :).

Comment: Noticed that when the values are: money=1000, last_prize=100, total_prizes=9 << works. But when I change total_prizes to 10 or more it doesn't. When the total_prizes is 10 the ratio gets to be zero. When it's more than 10 the ratio gets to be negative.

Comment: "The code is not working because the last place can't be 100$" << can't understand that. Any rule apply to it? And,

Comment: Read my coment. If the last place is 1$ and the above prizes should be bigger and you have to pay 11people, you can't do that with 10$.
Because if the last gets 1$ the rest of 10 must also get atleast 1$  that makes a prize amount of at least 11$ :) . So if you have 1000$ and 20prizes it's impossible to give the last place 100$ .

Comment: The maximum value of the last place is: MONEY / TOTAL_PRIZES . So if you have 1000$ and 20 prizes, the last value can be maximum 50$

Just use this defines and you will understand:
last_prize 50$
total_prizes 20
money 1000$

Comment: You're amazing. Really! I've edited with your solution, just changed it so it outputs to the console for easier and quicker operation. I think I'm getting the idea... working on it (:

Comment: I used file output so I can copy the output and place it here.  

----------------READ THIS------------------

If you use last prize:51, total_prizes20, money: 1000. You can see that it isn't correct because the first place gets less then the last.... try to undertand this :D . Good Night! (2:00AM :> )

Comment: Hahaha! Trying! I swear! (: Really, have a good night my friend! Also marking your answer as the official answer. Again, thank you!

Comment: Oh, and you could try to use geometric progression instead of arithmetic (so that the difference betweeen prizes would pe in procents eg: 30% )

Comment: Well you know a lot happened since yesterday - I've made it bring really nice results with several other options, so, I think it's enough (:

Comment: There is a bug in this line  first_prize=2*money/total_prizes+last_prize; should be first_prize=2*money/total_prizes-last_prize;

Answer (score 4):

You could make a simple formula like.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
FILE *g=fopen("output.out","w");
int i;
int prizes[21];
int money=1000;
int main(){
    for(i=1;i<=20;i++){
       prizes[i]=(float)(15+(20-i))/100*money;
       money-=prizes[i];
    fprintf(g,"%d) %d\n",i,prizes[i]);
      }
return 0;
}
```

This will output:

```
1) 340
2) 217
3) 141
4) 93
5) 62
6) 42
7) 29
8) 20
9) 14
10) 10
11) 7
12) 5
13) 4
14) 3
15) 2
16) 2
17) 1
18) 1
19) 1
20) 0
```

But you can change the values to anything you would like :).
This is just a fast&easy way to do this.

The starting ideea for this algorithm was:
1st prize: 30% from all the money (1000$) = ~330$
2nd prize: 30% from the rest (670$) = ~201
3rd prize: 30% from the rest... etc...
If you replace (15+(20-i)) with 20 let's say, you get this output:
Just change that value to get diffrent results.

```
1) 200
2) 160
3) 128
4) 102
5) 82
6) 65
7) 52
8) 42
9) 33
10) 27
11) 21
12) 17
13) 14
14) 11
15) 9
16) 7
17) 6
18) 4
19) 4
20) 3
```

**EDIT:**
And one more thing. After splitting all the money using that algorithms there may still be some money left (because the last one gets x% from the rest). You can add the left-over to the first place...

Comment: Very good one Cristy thanks, yet it doesn't work well with all combinations nor it generate values which sum up to 1000 (or close, the total sum of the second output is around 980 and a bit).

Comment: @Poni As I told in my edit, there may be some money left which you can use to buy some Whiskey :)) (just kidding). Add the money left to the first place. This is just a simple alogirthm, if you want something that's more complex you should check some math solving of this problem (arithmetic/geometric progresions or something like that)

Comment: Check out my edit to the OP. Might get you to a better solution (: Thanks again, really appriciate the effort!

Comment: Agree on your edit yet I'll try, before doing that, to solve it, so it'll distribute it even better.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for a pool - I wanted the 3 levels of individual prizes to have the same relative ratio (70%/20%/10%) but recognized the likelyhood of ties, so I had to account for that.  I didn't want to just split the pot then award prizes since you might end up with ties for second and an individual second place winner getting less than the third place winner.

P(i) = Size of Prize
N(i) = Number of winners

1) Sum (over i) P(i)*N(i) = $1000

2) P(1)/P(2) = 70/20

3) P(2)/P(3) = 20/10

In my case, 3 equations in 3 unknowns - which I solved to get a unique solution.

For your example P(1) = $300.  I would just specify successive ratios of prizes and solve the linear system of equations.

Also consider looking [here](http://stats.nj.com/golf/tournament.asp?tour=PGA&tournament=29) for the distribution of golf prizes at the recent British Open Championship.  I'm not saying that the PGA could do a better job than the talent at this website, but it a demonstration of your question in action.

Comment: Actually it's a algebraic solution to a problem, not an algorithm, so it's not easily coded.  If you formulate the problem as n equations in n unknowns, you can solve for each unknown with an general linear algebra solver.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose total money M, you want distribute in n pools such that first person will get k times more than second and second gets k times more than third and so on. Suppose last one get x amount money then

x + k*x + k^2*x ... k^(n-1)*x = M
x(k^n-1)/(k-1) = M

Solve for x from this equation based on value of k you choose and distribute money :-)

Answer (score 0):

Formula in first line of Cristy is wrong.
first_prize=2*money/total_prizes+last_prize;
It should be first_prize=2*money/total_prizes - last_prize;

Here is my solution in python, this will add residual amount to top winners.

```
starting_amount = (((winnings * 2) / float(no_of_winners)) - last_amount)

difference = (last_amount - starting_amount) / float(no_of_winners - 1)
for rank in range(1, no_of_winners + 1):
    reward = starting_amount + difference * (rank - 1) 
    reward = round_amount(reward)
    winnings -= reward
    winning_amount[rank] = reward

residual_winnings = winnings
residual_shares = {1: 0.5, 2: 0.3, 3: 0.2} 

if no_of_winners < 3: 
    winning_amount[1] += residual_winnings
else:
    for rank in residual_shares:
        reward = residual_winnings * residual_shares[rank]
        reward = round_amount(reward)
        winning_amount[rank] += reward
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a few hours trying to come up with an algorithm that will distribute prizes. Here is my solution based off things I saw on various forums. This code is in Ruby. This has worked great for me.

```
def self.get_prize_array(money,total_prizes)
    prizes = []  
    p = 0.7 # tweek this for distribution of payout 
    n = total_prizes
    l = money
    (1..total_prizes).each do |r|
       prizes[r-1] = ((1 - p) / (1 - p**n) * p**(r - 1)) * l   # p**n is p to the nth power
    end   
    return prizes
  end
```