# Distributing prize pots evenly

Tags: php, algorithm, math

So the most help I've seen is from this thread here: [Distribute prizes for a tournament system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409116/distribute-prizes-for-a-tournament-system).

I've read a few other ones but they weren't of no help to me due to it being into a language or just a series of letters that is slightly difficult to understand.

So my prize value is for example `482.17` spread across 45 participants, what I want to do is distribute this value in 15% intervals.

From the previous thread I've done my best to translate this

```
int i;
int prizes[21];
int money=1000;
for(i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
    prizes[i] = (float) (15+(20-i)) / 100 * money;
    money -= prizes[i];
    fprintf(g,"%d) %d\n",i,prizes[i]);
}
```

to PHP which is what I have below.

```
    $Points       = 482.17
    $countPlayers = 45;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $countPlayers; $i++) {
        /* Calculate Points */
        $reward = (float) (15 + ($countPlayers - $i)) / 100 * $Points;
        $Points -= $reward;

        echo $getPlayers[i] . " - " . $Points;
    }
```

So typically 15% of `482.17` should be `72.33` meaning 1st place should be getting that value. But instead it returns a value of `164.26`. Though the example claims to be doing it 30% but even 30% of 482.17 is `144.65`

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you're asking for.

```
<?php
$countPlayers =45;
$prizes[$countPlayers];
$money=482.17;
for($i = 1; $i <= $countPlayers; $i++){
    // Take 15% of the remaining pot each time
    $prizes[$i] = ($money * 15.0)/100.0;
    $money -= $prizes[$i];
    echo $i.")".number_format($prizes[$i],2,'.','')."\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: It does most of what it's supposed to do, but it doesn't utilize all of the `$money`. So when I use this example on `$countPlayers=45;` it works but has a very minor differential of a value that's pretty much `0.01`. However, if you replace `45` with `8` then you still have `100` worth of `$money` left over.

Comment: I took your maths. The example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3410220/3491475 does it in a much more funky way. It should be easy to convert that from C code into PHP.

Comment: Any idea as to why the results that it returns is odd?